# Last modified time of file in C

Tags: c, linux, time, strftime

I am trying to get the last modified time of a file in C/Linux, but the time always comes out wrong.

```
struct stat attrib;
stat("/etc/example/file.txt", &attrib);
char time[50];
strftime(time, 50, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime(&attrib.st_mtime));
```

Printing time gives me "2024-05-01 15:35:21". The year and day are obviously wrong. I have tried different options such as gmtime instead of localtime, but it does not produce the correct output. using "ls -l" shows the correct Month, Day, and Year...So I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"` change to `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`

Comment: Did you check that the `stat()` call worked.  If not, you're working with random data.

Answer (score 4):

It is printing correctly.

```
// try.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct stat attrib;
    stat("file.txt", &attrib);
    char time[50];
    strftime(time, 50, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime(&attrib.st_mtime));
    printf ("%s\n", time);
}

$ gcc -otry try.c
$ ./try
2017-05-08 08:43:42

$ ls -ls file.txt
4 -rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1 12 May  8 08:43 file.txt
```